# How to handle race conditions in distributed programming?

Tags: design-patterns, distributed-computing, distributed, race-condition, distributed-system

I can't seem to find much online about this. In distributed programming, there are many scenarios where race conditions pose a risk. For example, if I have a chat system where I want to limit the user count in each room to 100. Many concurrent joins may lead to more than 100 users in a single room due to race conditions. The only solution I can think of is to use a distributed lock. However, I feel that there are cleaner ways to address this/these issues. Are there any guides or resources online about this?

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to a consistency model you want to embrace. 
If you want strong consistency in your system(each node in your system sees the same counter value at any point in time and that value is always "valid") - there is no way you can escape using distributed consensus algorithm(distributed lock is a case of such alg).

But you can overcome it by changing your expectations. For example, you might accept that counter value will be "valid" eventually("eventual consistency" model) and use CRDT for a counter and solve transaction conflicts "later".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you personally use a distributed lock for the scenario that I mentioned in my question?

Comment: If I really don't want more than 100 users, and I expect a lot of them joining the chat at roughly the same time(high traffic service) - probably. The thing is - if your chat rooms are small(up to 100 users) it means that any chat room may fit into a single server and you can assume that the system is not distributed(at least for that particular room) and users local storage or relational DB to track users who joined.

Comment: But you can't really make that assumption if you want high availability? The main reason that I'm going for distribution is to avoid a single point of a failure.